# Check if popup is active inside chrome extension background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have build a chrome extension with a popup view and background script. What I don't understand is how the background script can figure out if the popup is open/active or not.

I have the following code in my background script:

```
// Listen for active-tab change
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, tabs => {
  
        const url = tabs[0].url;
        if (url === '') {
            chrome.tabs.update(activeInfo.tabId, { url: 'https://google.com' });
        }

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            activeTabId: activeInfo.tabId,
            url
        });
    })
});
```

What this code does is that if the active tab `url === ""` it is set to **google.com**

This code has 2 problems.

1. it always sets the url to google.com even if the extension popup is not active and 2) the url of the extension-popup is also set google.com

Here is some extra code, which shows how I create the popup:

```
 const popup = await chrome.windows.create({
      url: `index.html#?tabid=${tab.id}`,
      type: 'popup',
      height: 800,
      width: 900
    });
```

Any suggestion how I can detect if the extension-popup is open and how I can skip popup-tabs?

Comment: A direct answer would be to add `.catch(e => .....)` which will run when the popup is not shown, but a proper solution depends on what you want to achieve. For example, it's impossible to switch to a different tab in a window without closing the extension's action popup shown in this window, so maybe you're not using the standard action popup or maybe you can simply move the code into popup.js so that it runs automatically when the popup is shown.

Comment: The reason I want to set an url, is that the popup sends messages to the content script. However, if the active-tab doesn't have a url/page, the content script is not present yet. So, for the popup to work the active tab needs to have a url. But I could instead let the popup send a message to the background script to set the url. I have to investigate this!

Comment: If you use the standard action popup then you can simply use chrome.runtime.sendMessage in the content script, so when the popup is open, its onMessage will receive the message. It's still unclear what exactly you want to achieve though, so a more complete example of code would be helpful...

Comment: AlI I want is to send messages from the popup to the content script. However, I noticed that when you have a tab with its initial url `'chrome://new-tab-page/'` the content script is not loaded. So you cannot communicate. In such a case I tried to give the tab an url using the background script. I've also added the code which creates the popup!

Comment: chrome:// pages can't run content scripts by design. To send a message to a content script yo uneed chrome.tabs.sendMessage with a tab id, not chrome.runtime.sendMessage, but a better solution may be the one I suggested initially (chrome.runtime.sendMessage from the content script).

Comment: Yes, I understand what my options are now. Thanks a lot for the help!!